# Effect of pair of complex zeros on system response

Tags: transfer-function

Talking about continuous system transfer functions (so s-domain), a lot of resources are available to estimate the effect of one real zero on the system response.
However, I did not find anywhere a good resource that states how a pair of dominant complex-conjugate-zeros affect the system response.
Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Are you talking about continuous or discrete transfer functions (so Laplace transform/s-domain or z-transform/z-domain)? And what do you exactly mean with complex zeros, zero or non-zero real part?

Comment: I edited my question to include more details. In the most general case, I'm interested in the effect of complex-conjugate-zeros (so the real part may be non-zero)